# ping command with UDP client-server

Tags: udp, ping, mininet

I am confused about usage of ping command on mininet. When I implement UDP server and client and execute them with mininet, do I have to use ping command to measure packet loss, delay etc. Or ping command is not used for measuring statistics of UDP server client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to implement your own ping?

Ping is simply a tool that uses ICMP datagrams to measure point-to-point network latencies and other such things.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc792.txt

Comment: No, I am asking that when I send my own packets through UDP client to the UDP server (I have implemented them in c++ and execute them like first writing xterm h1 h2 in mininet and then on these terminals I just execute my server-client cpp files) , and when I send those packets that are different in size for example 100 bytes, can I still use ping for learning statistics about this packets that I sent from client? As I understand I can't but I still cant find what to use.

Comment: ICMP datagrams are much more tightly managed than something you would write.  You can use ping in parallel to measure such things, but that won't be terribly useful.   Personally, I would use WireShark on both ends of your connection to get a better idea of how your UDP applications are working.